# How to get the BF3 style "Upcoming Unlock" in BF4?

Tags: battlefield-4, battlelog

In the battlelog for BF3, there's a screen I loved to use, which is called Upcoming Unlocks, which show the closest assignement, weapons, weapons upgrades to unlock in percentages.

I loved this screen because it forced me to play different weapons and style regularly, but I can't see it for BF4.

Is it hidden somewhere or do I have to find a way to do it myself?

Comment: You probably mean "upcoming", not uncoming. Correct that, it'll make this question easier to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably mean "Upcoming Unlocks". And yes, they are missing in the BF4 battlelog. The closes thing to that would be the *Suggestions* on the right on the start page of the [BF4 Battlelog](http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf4/). There you see three things that will be unlocked soon and you can choose what will be shown there yourself. However, it is very limited in my opinion.

If you are willing to use other sources, you can go to [bf4stats.com](http://bf4stats.com/) and search for your player profile. There is a section **Upcoming weapon unlocks** which you see here at [another players profile I picked randomly](http://bf4stats.com/pc/pcell_Si) that shows:

- **Weapons**
- **Weapon unlocks**
- **Weapon service stars**

Further down there is also a section **Upcoming vehicle unlocks** and another **Upcoming medals**

Comment: That is perfect good sir. And yes that was upcoming.

Comment: for the weapons I just created a javascript that I use with [dotjs](https://github.com/defunkt/dotjs), it re-sort the weapons stats of the battlelog by kills left, battlepacks on top